# Issue Generating ~\key.jks file

Tags: android, flutter

I am following the instructions to deploy a Flutter app to the play store. https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

I have reached the point title Create a Keystore

I am prompted to enter a password, my name, etc, and get through all of the steps in that process until I say "yes" and then I receive the following error

```
[Storing ~/key.jks]
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~\key.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~\key.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1144)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:343)
        at sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:336)
```

I'm not sure how to get around this.

I've tried using each of the following commands:
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool" -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key

this one results in the error above.

I've also tried:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1\bin\keytool" -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key

this one results in the following error:

```
[Storing ~/key.jks]
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~\key.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ~\key.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

I have also tried adding each of these directories to path and instead issuing the command laid out in the docs:
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key

but that gives me this error:
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Anybody run into this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux and MacOS, '~' is a shortcut for "my home directory", so `~/key.jks` expands to, for example, `/home/fluttercoder/key.jks`. Obviously, this folder doesn't exist on Windows.

Choose a different folder on Windows, for example, `c:\Users\fluttercoder\keys\`, so the file becomes `c:\Users\fluttercoder\keys\key.jks`. (Be careful of any Windows folders with spaces in. Best to avoid them; otherwise enclose them in double quotes.)

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you need to create keystore(.jks) file.

> 1. goto Build-->Generate Signed Apk-->select apk-->select path with filename(which you want to create newly)-->set all parameters(required
>      information)-->finally select release and checkmark v1 and v2-->then
>      find your apk in release folder-->upload this apk to play store.

Or

just put correct path in below command line

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore  -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key

:)